# Keras import in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use keras and the _obtain_input_shape function which seems to be an absolute mess. Now the following error keeps coming up.

ImportError: You need to first `import keras` in order to use `keras_applications`. For instance, you can do:

```
import keras
from keras_applications import vgg16
```

Or, preferably, this equivalent formulation:

```
from keras import applications
```

The message is very handy and helpful, but if I do what it instructs me to do (either option) the ImportError persists. Has anyone else encountered this?
My Keras version is 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Keras can be imported directly from tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

and then

```
app = tensorflow.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=True,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None,
    pooling=None,
    classes=1000,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
)
```